# How do you get IndexOf of a string with multiple possible chars?

Tags: c#, char, indexof

I need a function which can get the first index of one of multiple possible chars. I don't want to use regex because of the bad performance. I tried getting the min of two IndexOf(s) but it doesn't work when it is contained in one string and not the other because -1 is smaller than both indexes.

```
public static int IndexOf (this string s, char a, char b) => 
    Math.Min(s.IndexOf(a), s.IndexOf(b));
```

Comment: I found you can use IndexOfAny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a bit *more complex*, but I hope *more convenient* solution:

```
// 1. Let's return not only index, but the char found as well
// 2. Let's accept arbitrary number of characters
// 3. Let's not interfere with existing IndexOf, IndexOfAny methods : IndexOfAnyChar
public static (int index, char value) IndexOfAnyChar(this string s, params char[] toFind) {
  //DONE: input parameters validation
  if (null == s)
    return (-1, default(char)); // or throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(s))
  else if (null == toFind || toFind.Length <= 0)
    return (-1, default(char)); // or throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(toFind))

  int bestIndex = -1;
  char bestChar = default(char);

  foreach (char c in toFind) {
    // for the long strings let's provide count for efficency
    int index = s.IndexOf(c, 0, bestIndex < 0 ? s.Length : bestIndex);

    if (index >= 0) {
      bestIndex = index;
      bestChar = c;
    }
  }

  return (bestIndex, bestChar);
}
```

Demo:

```
var result = "abcde".IndexOfAnyChar('e', 'z', 'd');

// to get index only:
// int index = "abcde".IndexOfAnyChar('e', 'z', 'd').index; 

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
(3, d)
```

Comment: Great answer. This solution runs circles around other ones performance-wise. Better use it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, it's to get the smallest index between the indexes of two characters in a string, but the problem is that if only one of them exists, the index of the other is returned because it's `-1`.

One way to solve this is to test for `-1` in the first string, and then decide what to do with the second:

```
public static int IndexOf (this string s, char a, char b) => s.IndexOf(a) == -1
    // If it's not in 'a', return its index in 'b'
    ? s.IndexOf(b)                               
    : s.IndexOf(b) == -1       
        // Else if it's not in 'b', return its index in 'a'              
        ? s.IndexOf(a)                    
        // Otherwise, return the smallest index between 'a' and 'b'       
        : Math.Min(s.IndexOf(a), s.IndexOf(b));
```

However, **there is a problem with this extension method!!**

Because there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, this method will be hidden by a [native overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32__) of the `IndexOf` method  that takes a `char` and an `int`, which returns *"the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting at the specified position."*

I believe this is because native methods are evaluated and chosen (if there's an implicit match) before any extension methods are evaluated, but I may be wrong.

To get around this problem, we can simply give the method a different name:

```
public static int IndexOfFirst (this string s, char a, char b) => s.IndexOf(a) == -1
    ? s.IndexOf(b)                               
    : s.IndexOf(b) == -1       
        ? s.IndexOf(a)                    
        : Math.Min(s.IndexOf(a), s.IndexOf(b));
```

Also, we can make use of a `params` argument to let this method handle `0` to many characters from which to find the first index:

```
public static int IndexOfFirst(this string s, params char[] args) =>
    (args?.Any(arg => s.IndexOf(arg) > -1)).GetValueOrDefault()
        ? args.Select(arg => s.IndexOf(arg))
              .Where(index => index > -1)
              .Min()
        : -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer:

```
using System;
public static int IndexOf (this string s, char a, char b) => unchecked((int)Math.Min((uint)s.IndexOf(a), (uint)s.IndexOf(b)));
```

or for more parameters:

```
using System.Linq;
public static int IndexOf (this string s, params char[] arr) => unchecked((int)arr.Min(i => (uint)s.IndexOf(i)));
```

This works because -1 as a uint on an unchecked settings, -1 is equivalent to uint.MaxValue which means that that is considered the highest possible value meaning that min will pick a smaller index if one exists.

**EDIT:** If the chars you are dealing with are the same letter if different cases, you can do:

```
using System;
public static int IndexOf (this string s, char a) => s.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: So it sounds like if neither character exists, this method will return `uint.MaxValue` instead of `-1`, is that correct?

Comment: @RufusL, since it is cast back to int, it will return -1.